# Android app stopped working - servlets and Httpget

Tags: android, tomcat, servlets

I have a problem. I am starting my adventure with servlets and Android and I designed a simple servlet which writes "Hello world". Now I want to receive this message in my Android app. My code:

```
public class MyServlet extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button button;
TextView outputText;

public static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/ServletExample/HelloServletExample";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewsById();

    button.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void findViewsById() {
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    outputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputTxt);
}

public void onClick(View view) {

    String output = null;



        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            output = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    //} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //} catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //}



    outputText.setText(output);


}
```

My servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/HelloServletExample")
public class HelloServletExample extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public HelloServletExample() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Hello World");

}

}
```

I don't know why but my app crashes. I tried commenting out some lines and it turns out that what is the problem is this line:

```
HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
```

Why?

Comment: if you comment `HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();` line then it's working? if yes then search for `NetworkOnMainThreadException` in logcat after app crash

Comment: I do have this exception. Why? My app is for Android 4 and I read on the Internet that the way I am doing this is a proper approach to retrieve data.

Comment: Oo, I have to use AsyncTask?

Comment: no need to use AsyncTask if you are using android 4

Answer (score 0):

if you are using  **API level >= 9** then no need to use `AsyncTask` for making network request from Ui Thread just add [StrictMode.ThreadPolicy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.html) in Activity onCreate method as:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().
                                                   permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: Well, with this 10.0.2.2 the app hangs... When I change it to localhost it receives nothing. Where is the problem?

But thank you, it does not crash anymore!

Comment: @user1928115 : if this answer help u in solving current issue then mark it as answer .Thanks